# Understanding how to call a procedure properly in IBM db2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm working on writing a query to create or replace a stored procedure called UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE that takes two integer parameters.

I've successfully created the query, but now I'm having trouble executing it properly. I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

Here is my query:

```
-- Ex 3 Question 1 Write the structure of a query to create or replace a 
-- stored procedure called UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE that takes a in_School_ID 
-- parameter as an integer and a in_Leader_Score parameter as an integer. 

-- Don't forget to use the #SET TERMINATOR statement to use the @ for the 
-- CREATE statement terminator.

--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (
    IN in_School_ID  INTEGER, IN in_Leader_Score INTEGER) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    IF in_Leader_Score >=  80 THEN 
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very_Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score>= 60 and in_Leader_Score <= 79  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  40 and in_Leader_Score <= 59  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Average'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  20 and in_Leader_Score <= 39  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSE
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    END IF;
  END 
  @
```

This was successful. Now, I'm attempting to call the procedure:

```
--Run stored procedure
CALL UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE(610038, 50);
```

But I get this error:

```
Status:
Failed
Error message
Value "Average" is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.31.10
Learn more about this error
```

Any tips? I'm using sql in IBM's db2. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It is telling you that the database table CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS has a column named Leaders_Icon  whose length is too short to fit the value you want to put into that column.  Look at your table definition, and fix it, or use shorter strings when setting column Leaders_Icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH MAN I FOUND THE PROBLEM.

```
LEADERS_ICON    VARCHAR     Y   4   0
```

When I went to look at the table definition, the LEADERS_ICON column has a character limit of 4 it looks like. So I will either adjust the length of the column, or update the query to use "Avg" instead of "Average" to solve the problem.

EDIT: I'm a genius (aka rookie), this worked.

First, I altered the table column so that the strings would fit:

```
--update column LEADERS_ICON in CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS table varchar limit
ALTER TABLE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
    ALTER COLUMN LEADERS_ICON 
    SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR (15);
```

Then I just ran the call again, and it worked!